# Apply a function to only array slices which satisfy a condition (NumPy)

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, advanced-indexing

I have an array `A[i,j]`. The last index contains various input values for a function `myfunc` that will be applied for each `i` and produce an output `B[i]`. However, many values indexed by `j` will not contribute to `B`, so I would like to avoid unnecessary calls of `myfunc`. This can be accomplished by slicing out the relevant values with conditional indexing such as `C = C[C>mythreshold]` with for loops relatively easily as in the MWE below:

```
def myfunc(X):
    return np.square(X).sum()
A = np.floor(np.random.rand(3,4)*100)
mythreshold = 10
(N1, N2) = A.shape
B = np.zeros(N1)
for i in range(N1):
    C = A[i,:]
    C = C[C>mythreshold]
    B[i] = myfunc(C)
```

I had to break this up into for loops so I could remove slices of `A` without removing slices of the full array. This was since I cannot drop elements of `A[i,:]` for one `i` without dropping the corresponding elements for another `i`. For speed, however, I would like to vectorize wherever possible - to avoid for loops and do this for all `i` in one go. How can I do this?

Note: That was an MWE; the actual case has larger array dimensions, so that my arrays would be `A[i,j,k,l]` and `B[i,j]`, so the for loop example would be something like the code below. I think the extra dimensions wouldn't complicate things, but it's worth mentioning just in case.

```
(N1, N2, N3, N4) = A.shape
for i in range(N1):
    for j in range(N2):
        C = A[i,j,:,:].flatten()
        C = C[C>mythreshold]
        B[i,j] = myfunc(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [10]: A = np.floor(np.random.rand(3,4)*2*mythreshold)
In [11]: A
Out[11]: 
array([[14.,  4.,  1.,  8.],
       [11., 11.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 8.,  6., 18., 12.]])
In [12]: (N1, N2) = A.shape
    ...: B = np.zeros(N1)
    ...: for i in range(N1):
    ...:     C = A[i,:]
    ...:     C = C[C>mythreshold]
    ...:     B[i] = myfunc(C)
    ...: 
In [13]: B
Out[13]: array([196., 242., 468.])
```

A threshold test for the whole array:

```
In [14]: A>mythreshold
Out[14]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Make a copy, and set the other values to 0 (or something innocuous):

```
In [15]: A1 = A.copy(); A1[A<=mythreshold]=0
In [16]: np.square(A1).sum(axis=1)
Out[16]: array([196., 242., 468.])
```

That's doesn't avoid applying the function to all elements, but it avoids iterating on rows.   Usually avoiding python level loops speeds up `numpy` code.  But if your function can't be "vectorized" as I do with the `axis` parameter, or where it is so complex that including those "0" values is expensive, then this is not the way to go.

If your function includes `ufunc`, you could use its `where` parameter

```
In [17]: mask = A>mythreshold
In [18]: out = np.zeros_like(A)
In [19]: np.square(A, out=out, where=mask)
Out[19]: 
array([[196.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [121., 121.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 324., 144.]])
In [20]: _.sum(axis=1)
Out[20]: array([196., 242., 468.])
```

Usually this `where` is used when certain values give bad results, like divide by 0 or log of a negative.  I don't think it's a time saver, but haven't done timings to confirm this.

Comment: Thank you! This sort of masking is what I've been doing in lieu of omitting the below-threshold elements. The function I'm applying isn't very complex, so for now I will just call it good.